# ng click does not work in custom modal and function not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a customized modal, but when I run ng-Click does not work and it's not firing the function.

```
commonService.modalDialog({
                                    state: 'default',
                                    header: 'my header message',
                                    body: '<div class="form-group">' +
                                        '<div>Article Name</div>' +
                                        '<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="test()">test</button>'+
...
...


$scope.test = function(){
   console.log("ng-click fired");

};
```

Comment: Please share a reproducible code snippet.

Comment: So the problem is with ng-click, not the modal?